# Magento 2.0.2 - Steps to see custom theme

Tags: theme, magento-2.0.2

By following other tickets and documentation. I have been able to see new custom theme in admin section based on the next steps:

Here the steps I have done:

1. I have created folder structure under 'Magentoroot'/app/design/frontend/myvendor/mytheme/

[image: Folders structure]
.

2. Then I have added file: 'theme_dir'/theme.xml

> ```
> <theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
>      <title>My Theme</title> <!-- your theme's name -->
>      <parent>Magento/blank</parent> <!-- the parent theme, in case your theme inherits from an existing theme -->
>      <media>
>          <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image> <!-- the path to your theme's preview image -->
>      </media>
>  </theme>
> ```
>
> .

3. Then I have added file: 'theme_dir'/composer.json

> ```
> {
>     "name": "myvendor/theme-frontend-mytheme",
>     "description": "N/A",
>     "require": {
>         "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
>         "magento/theme-frontend-blank": "100.0.*",
>         "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
>     },
>     "type": "magento2-theme",
>     "version": "100.0.1",
>     "license": [
>         "OSL-3.0",
>         "AFL-3.0"
>     ],
>     "autoload": {
>         "files": [
>             "registration.php"
>         ]
>     } }
> ```

.
4. Then I have added file: 'theme_dir'/registration.php :

```
<?php /**  * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.  * See COPYING.txt for license details.  */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/myvendor/mytheme',
    __DIR__ );
```

.

5. Then I updated ''/dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js - just below luma:

   ```
   luma: {
       area: 'frontend',
       name: 'Magento/luma',
       locale: 'en_US',
       files: [
           'css/styles-m',
           'css/styles-l'
       ],
       dsl: 'less'
   },
   mytheme: {
       area: 'frontend',
       name: 'myvendor/mytheme',
       locale: 'en_US',
       files: [
           'css/styles-m',
           'css/styles-l'
       ],
       dsl: 'less'
   },
   ```

.

6. Then deleted var from root
7. Then I flushed cache
8. Then I ran from CLI - in this step the new theme was not shown in logs:
   magento setup:static-content:deploy
9. Then when I go to Admin/Content/Themes and I am able to find new theme.

Answer (score 1):

you also have to use the theme in a store I think.

Goto Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Design for this